# Facebook lookalike audience associate with campaign or adset

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-marketing-api

[image: originid]I am creating a lookalike audience its working well. Using curl PHP but I am passing a parameter origin_ids for with value campaign id but it creates lookalike audience and not associate with campaign id that have passed.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/lookalike-audiences/

Here is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/'.$id.'/customaudiences');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$post = array(
    
    'subtype' => 'LOOKALIKE',
     'origin_audience_id' => $audID, 
    'lookalike_spec' => array(
    'origin_ids' => $_REQUEST['campaign_id'],
    'starting_ratio' => $starting_ratio,
    'ratio' => $ratio,
    'conversion_type' => 'campaign_conversions',
    'country' => $_REQUEST['con'],
  ),
    'access_token' => $access_token
);
$post['lookalike_spec'] = json_encode($post['lookalike_spec']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to deliver an array of integers (as described on Marketing API).

```
lookalike_spec.origin_ids
type: array of integers
```

Looks odd, but try this (and please make sure, your `campaign_id` is not empty):

```
    'origin_ids' => [$_REQUEST['campaign_id']],
```